# Regex to Find Anything Between Multiple Delimiters

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to match anything between different delimiters, using a Java based regex engine/interpreter.  The text I'm after is the server.domain.com  I do not believe I can use any Java either, only a regular expression. The log will only have one OR the other, never both. This must be accomplished with a single regex, or the application will have to be re-written.

Examples of the logs:

```
Host = server.domain.com|
```

**OR**

```
Host="server.domain.com"
```

Thus far I've tried the following, along with a number of other combinations...

```
Host="(.*?)"|Host\s=\s(.*?)\|
```

I must also use Host as part of the delimiter, as it is parsing out of a log with many other similar pieces.

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: And can there be any embedded double quotes/pipe signs?

Comment: I'm attempting to extract the server.domain.com text btw. =)

Comment: There are two questions in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) that may help, which are both listed under "Common Validation Tasks > Internet": [matching urls](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/2736496) and the [host/port part](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22697740/578411)

Comment: Dear Mr. aliteralmind,  I <3 you very much!  I just learned about using non capture groups and that did the trick!  See my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to aliteral mind, I learned about non capture groups and that was key...

Behold!...

Host(?:\s=\s|=\")(.*?)(?:\||\")

Answer (score 1):

For the example given, you could use:

```
^Host\s*=\s*(?:")?(?:[^|"])+[|"]$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CD9m1DxUrAqIbff2)

it will also accept

```
host=server.domain.com"
```

but if the logs are **either / or** that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: This is the right approach. Regular expressions aren't the tool you want to validate that your delimeters match.

Comment: This is a great response and explanation, but it does not work.  I've even tried removing the anchors and nothing... =/  It highlights the entire selection and not just the server.domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with both the string

```
    String str1 = "Host = server.domain.com|";
    String str2 = "Host=\"server.domain.com\"";

    //Host(no or one space)=(" or one space)server.domain.com(| or ")
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Host\\s?=[\\\"|\\s]server.domain.com[\\||\\\"]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str1);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("found");
    }
```

You can try this one also if no of spaces are not known on either side of equal to.

```
//Host(zero or more spaces)=(zero or more spaces)(" or spaces)server.domain.com(" or |)
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Host\\s*=\\s*[\\\"|\\s*]server.domain.com[\\\"|\\|]");
```

Comment: I tried both of the regex's, but it did not match anything.  Also, I'm not using any code, only the regular expression.

Comment: Damn it you guys rock!  Thanks Braj

Comment: Now you can test your Regex here and Please tell me what pattern is not matched by given Regex in my post.