# how to use regex to beautifully dissect urls

Tags: regex, url

I want to use regex to get an arrayLike object from the params giving to url

e.g.

```
http://mysite/myPeople?one=jose&two=emily&three=john
```

basically what it does is this

```
    function interpretUrl(url){

        var reg = /\?([^&?=]*)=([^&?=]*)/g; //what am i doing wrong?

        //some logic here
        reg.exec(url)

        return {
            param: [
                one: 'jose',
                two: 'emily',
                three: 'john'
            ],
            root:
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's nice. What's stopping you?

Comment: This is answered in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), both listed under "Common Validation Tasks": [matching urls](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/2736496) and [matching host/port](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22697740/578411)

Comment: big thanks, aliteralmind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get all the parameters from query string:

```
var re = /([^?&]+)=([^&]*)/g,
    matches = {},
    input = "http://mysite/myPeople?one=jose&two=emily&three=john";
while (match = re.exec(input.substr(input.indexOf('?')+1))) matches[match[1]] = match[2];

console.log(matches);
//=> {one: "jose", two: "emily", three: "john"}
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to do it more than once without the loop? what was I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think loop can be avoided here due to use of `/g` flag in `exec`. Javascript doesn't have equivalent of PHP's `preg_match_all`.

Comment: whats the use of the /g and is it possible to matchall without adding it?

Comment: `g` is for global to find all the matches. Without `g` it will only find first pair instead of all.

Comment: but looks like even so it will stop on the first pair it finds?

Comment: Just copy paste above code and test it. I also provided you output.