# Regex Pattern matching for an URL

Tags: java, regex

I have a method and input to that is an URL string. I would different types of URL (sample 5 URLs i have mentioned below)

```
String url1 = "http://domainName/contentid/controller_hscc.jsp?q=1" ;
String url2 = "http://domainName/contentid/controller.jsp?waitage=1" ;
String url3 = "http://domainName/contentid/controller_runner.jsp" ;
String url4 = "http://domainName/contentid/jump.jsp?q=5" ;
String url5 = "http://domainName/contentid/jump.jsp" ;
```

I need to find if this URL has controller*.jsp pattern in it. If so, I will have to write some other logic for it.

Now, I need to know how to write `* controller*.jsp` pattern in java

I wrote a regex this way and it returns false always

```
boolean retVal = Pattern.matches("^(controller)*", url) ;
```

**PS : I use JDK1.4**

**EDIT-1**

I tried below way. Still not woring

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String url = "http://domainName/contentid/controller_hscc.jsp?q=1" ;
        //String url = "baaaaab" ;
        String regex = "/controller(\\w+)?\\.jsp*" ;

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
        System.out.println(m.matches());
     }
}
```

Comment: Did that fix your problem?

Comment: FYI: Here are two answers from the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) that relate to your question: [validating urls](http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/2736496) and [validating urls with host/port](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22697740/578411). Both are listed under "Common Validation Tasks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String url = "http://domainName/contentid/controller_hscc.jsp?q=1" ;
        //String url = "baaaaab" ;
        String regex = "^.*?controller(\\w+)?\\.jsp.*?$" ;

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
        boolean retVal = Pattern.matches(regex, url) ;
        System.out.println(m.matches() + "__" + retVal);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Match it against the following regex:

`controller(\w+)?\.jsp`

### Demo

Comment: @Arun, Are you sure. Because As you can see from my Demo, it _does_ work

Comment: no sashank, its not working, can you copy-paste my code and test here http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: @Arun, Try this instead: `.*?controller(\w+)?\.jsp.*?`

Comment: @Arun, Sorry, I meant this: `^.*?controller(\w+)?\.jsp.*?$`

Comment: getting compilation exception in java .. String pattern = ".*?controller(\w+)?\.jsp.*?" ;

Comment: sashank. still get compilation issue :(

Answer (score 1):

```
String re = "controller.+jsp";
String str = "http://domainName/contentid/controller_hscc.jsp?q=1";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this working fine:

```
(controller.*\.jsp(\?.*)?)
```

see [here](http://regex101.com/r/bP5oC8).

As a java string, it should be `"(controller.*\\.jsp(\\?.*)?)"`

Moreover, it will give you two groups: the whole one and the part after the `?`.

You could also do it by splitting the url by `/`s, taking the last part and checking if that starts with `controller` - without using any regex.